# Bloquear campos dependiendo de valor en dropdownlist en el Backend

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño formulario en **C#** y **ASP.NET MVC** y requiero validar desde el controlador, o sea el backend que cuando tenga el valor CERRADO en el `dropdownlist` de Estatus automáticamente se bloqueen los demás campos, quiere decir, que queden en modo de solo lectura algo así como `readOnly`, incluyendo su botón de *Enviar*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto debajo del código de mi formulario `html` y el controlador para cargar los datos

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
                               
                               <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="email" for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    
                                </div><div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="area" for="ticketAreaAppliInput">Área:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketAreaAppliInput" type="text" name="area" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="ubicacion" for="ticketLocationAppliInput">Ubicación:</label>
                                        <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketLocationAppliInput" type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="CategoryDiv">
                                        <label class="required-field" name="category" for="ticketCategoryInput">Categoría:</label>
                                        <select onchange="validate(this)" id="ticketCategoryInput" name="category" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Categoria 1</option>
                                        <option>Categoria 2</option>
                                        </select>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="StatusDiv">
                                    <label for="ticketStatusInput">Estatus:</label>
                                    <select id="ticketStatusInput" name="status" class="form-control form-control-user" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona una opción</option><option>Abierto</option>
                                        <option>Cerrado</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                
                                <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

**FormController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateTicketFromDetails()
        {
            var ticketAreaAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketAreaAppliInput"];
            var ticketLocationAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketLocationAppliInput"];         
            var ticketCategoryInput = Request.Form["ticketCategoryInput"];
            var ticketStatusInput = Request.Form["ticketStatusInput"];
        try
            {
                TicketRegisterResult result;               
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    // I create a new record variable with all fields
                    var record = new TK_DT_RECORDS
                    {
                        TK_CT_STATUS_ID = ticketStatusInput,
                        TK_CT_CATEGORIES_ID = ticketCategoryInput
                    };
                    // We update the ticket data (this will always be done)
                    var model = new TicketRegisterModel();

                    // We create the new record in the record table and insert it
                    result = model.UpdateTicket(
                     ticketAreaAppliInput, ticketLocationAppliInput, record);

                    //If the ticket was not saved, the transaction is finished and we return the error message
                    if (!result.Success)
                        return Json(new TicketResult
                        {
                            IsValid = false,
                            Error = "The changes could not be saved, please try again."
                        });
                    scope.Complete();
                }   
            }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            //Falló al tratar de registrar datos en la base de datos
            foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);

            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "Ocurrió un error al crear el ticket, por favor inténtalo de nuevo."
            });
        }
return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = true
            });
            }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99499/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-salazar-bloquear-campos-dependiendo-de-valor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno como lo hablamos en el **chat**, tienes que hacer dos cosas, te recomiendo no mostrar el **botón Enviar** si el estado seleccionado es **cerrado**.

Primero tienes que validar si el estado es cerrado para que no permita realizar ningún cambio y ocultar el botón, bloqueas los campos así:

```
$("#StatusDiv select").val(data.Status);
//Validacion cuando esta CERRADO no se permita hacer ningun cambio
 if (data.Status == 'CDO') {
  $(":input").attr('disabled', true);

 } else {
   $(":input").removeAttr('disabled');
 }
```

Ahora este seria tu botón

```
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Enviar</button>
```

El cual debes bloquear si el estado es cerrado de esta forma, en la función que bloquea los campos agregas lo siguiente:

```
$("#submit").remove();
```

al remover el botón evitas que los usuarios puedan desbloquear el botón por la consola del navegador así el **estado** este **cerrado**, lo cual era tu problema.

El código quedaría de esta forma:

```
 $("#StatusDiv select").val(data.Status);
    //Validacion cuando esta CERRADO no se permita hacer ningun cambio
     if (data.Status == 'CDO') {
      $(":input").attr('disabled', true);
      $("#submit").remove();

     } else {
       $(":input").removeAttr('disabled');
     }
```